# DELETE Request with nodejs and Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, handlebars.js

I'm struggling to delete a row from a collection of my database using mongoose. The console said that deleting was successful (as I handled error), but when I check my database, the row is still here. I successfully add a member with a post request, but I was not able to delete it.
I suspect my route file or my hbs file.
Here is the code :

Index.js (the route part)

```
app.get('/delete',(req,res) => res.render('delete', {
    title:'Member App',
}));
```

routes/members.js

```
// Delete member : DELETE
router.get("/delete", (req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.params.id);
    Member.deleteOne({ _id: req.params.id }, function(err,data) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log(data);

                console.log("member successfully deleted")
        }
        else {
                console.log("error")
        }
    });
    res.redirect("/");
});
```

delete.hbs

```
<h1 class = "text-center mb-3">{{title}}</h1>
<form action="/delete" method ="DELETE" class="mb-4">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Id">Id</label>
    <input type="Id" name="Id" class ="form-control">
    
</div>
    

<input type="submit" value ="Delete member" class="btn">
</form>
```

The console : (it seems that the data from my callback is undefined)

```
Connected to mongoDB
undefined
{ n: 0, ok: 1, deletedCount: 0 }
member successfully deleted
```

Answer (score 2):

**Your input type tag is wrong.**

```
<input type="Id" name="Id" class ="form-control">
```

There is no "Id" type in input (see [input types values](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp))

**You don't use correct field**

```
req.params.id
```

Is used, but I don't see any params in your request.

You only have the body filled with Id so in order to use it, you should call :

```
req.body.Id
```

Comment: Yes you're right ,I modified it . But still ,the callback still respond with "successfully deleted" but the database is not updated

Answer (score 1):

First of all the absence of an error does not guarantee the deletion of a record in the database. So in this case prefer to use `findOneAndRemove` method.

Second `res.redirect("/");` will called before record removing has done, so redirect should be moved into callback function like:

```
Member.findOneAndRemove({ _id: req.params.id }, function(err, member) {
    if (!err && member) {
        console.log(member);
        console.log("member successfully deleted")
    }
    else {
        console.log("error")
    }
    res.redirect("/");
});
```

Comment: It's safety to use `findOneAndRemove` as you mentioned. In addition to your answer I'd say that using `deleteOne` can silently throw errors as it's defined in its [code](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/query.js#L2735). Despite the `undefined` filter, you always run the callback even if it's not been found.

Comment: Thank you @JoseVasquez. Edited back according your comment

Comment: Alright . When using postman for delete request ,it works perfectly well . What do you suggest me ?

Comment: Add `cosole.log(req.params)` and inspect your request